# How can a C++ compiler detect a non-const function body?

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-construction

Having stumbled over the following piece of code:

```
class Person
{
private:
    char name[10];
public:
    // this won't compile:
    char* getName_1() const {
        return name;
    }
    // this will: 
    const char* getName_2() const {
        return name;
    }
};
```

I am wondering exactly how a compiler can tell that `getName_1()` is not a const function. Because there is no piece of code inside the function body that is actually modifying a member variable.

Comment: I don't get the question.  `getName_1()` **is** a `const` function.

Comment: What do you mean by compiler telling or not telling? Question is unclear. Perhaps you might want to visit this page? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, but there is no piece of code that attempts to modify the array `name` - its address is only returned. My line of thinking up to now has been that in every `const` function every member is treated as a `const` member and thus cannot be modified, but obviously there is more to it ...

Comment: *in every const function every member is treated as a const member and thus cannot be modified* That's the jist of it.  Why do you think there is more to it than that?  The compoiler is complaining that you hare using a `char*` as the return type for `getName_1`.  You can't do that because in a const function `name` is a `const char[]`, not a `char[]` .

Comment: Got it. Its simply because the conversion from `const char*` to `char*` is not allowed.

Comment: Correct.  You can't implicitly cast away const, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `getName_1` is marked as `const` all fields of this class are treated as const.

So type of `name` in `getName_1` is `const char[10]`.

This can't be converted implicitly to `char *` (return type), so compiler reports an error.

Answer (score 2):

`getName_1()` *is* a const method, as it is literally marked as `const` in its declaration. That means its implicit `this` pointer is `const`, so the `name` member is treated as `const`, and so `getName_1()` can't return a *non-const* pointer to *const* data, which is why it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to other (correct) answers, this compiles:

```
class Person
{
private:
    char* name;
public:
    // this compiles:
    char* getName_1() const {
        return name;
    }
};
```

More than anything, this shows that contrary to popular myth, array in C++ is **not** a pointer.

Comment: Could you please expand?! This sounds interesting but I don’t quite understand the reasoning.

Comment: There is no special reasoning here. `const` modifier on member function treats all members as `const`, so `name` becomes `char* const name`. Nothing stops you from creating another non-const pointer and assign value of const pointer `name` to it.